# Can I take a photo in Unity using the device's camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photo

I'm entirely unfamiliar with Unity3D's more complex feature set and am curious if it has the capability to take a picture and then manipulate it. Specifically my desire is to have the user take a selfie and then have them trace around their face to create a PNG that would then be texture mapped onto a model.

I know that the face mapping onto a model is simple, but I'm wondering if I need to write the photo/carving functionality into the encompassing Chrome app, or if it can all be done from within Unity. I don't need a tutorial on how to do it, just asking if it's something that is possible.

Comment: For 2016 here's a FULL EXPLANATION of how to do this ... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/909967/getting-a-web-cam-to-play-on-ui-texture-image.html#answer-910020   ***CRITICAL***... follow the link to get the "magic" code to ***rotate, invert, spin*** the image correctly on iOS/Android.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You will want to look at the [WebCamTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html) functionality.

You create a WebCamTexture and call its [Play()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.Play.html) function which starts the camera. WebCamTexture, as any Texture, allows you to get the pixels via a GetPixels() call. This allows you to take a snapshot in when you like, and you can save this in a Texture2D. A call to [EncodeToPNG()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html) and subsequent write to file should get you there.

Do note that the code below is a quick write-up based on the documentation. I have not tested it. You might have to select a correct device if there are more than one available.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class WebCamPhotoCamera : MonoBehaviour 
{
    WebCamTexture webCamTexture;

    void Start() 
    {
        webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = webCamTexture; //Add Mesh Renderer to the GameObject to which this script is attached to
        webCamTexture.Play();
    }

    IEnumerator TakePhoto()  // Start this Coroutine on some button click
    {

    // NOTE - you almost certainly have to do this here:

     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); 

    // it's a rare case where the Unity doco is pretty clear,
    // http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html
    // be sure to scroll down to the SECOND long example on that doco page 

        Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(webCamTexture.width, webCamTexture.height);
        photo.SetPixels(webCamTexture.GetPixels());
        photo.Apply();

        //Encode to a PNG
        byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToPNG();
        //Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
        File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "photo.png", bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: now how to handle the camera rotation on say an android device when doing this?

Comment: What exactly is here to handle @Codejoy? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Too late for a reply? I've got the code sorted, attached it to a gameObject with a spriteRenderer.... it starts the camera, takes a photo if i press the button but does not show a live view.... any ideas what i'm doing wrong? (working in a 2D UI environment)

Comment: This is rotated randomly on devices.

Comment: All the camera does is deliver raw data. On some devices this indeed means that results may be rotated or flipped. You can address this via http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-videoRotationAngle.html

Comment: A bit late to the party, but i wanted to add a crucial information, about this solution. Camera on devices have two modes - video and photo. When you show preview, camera is in the video mode which will in most cases deliver a subpar quality. Creating a still photo from that input will provide really poor quality of the photo when compared to a regular photo taken by the same device.

Answer (score 7):

For those trying to get the camera to render live feed, here's how I managed to pull it off. First, I edited Bart's answer so the texture would be assigned on Update rather than just on Start:

```
void Start()
{
    webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    webCamTexture.Play();
}

void Update()
{
    GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = webCamTexture;
}
```

Then I attached the script to a GameObject with a RawImage component. You can easily create one by Right Click -> UI -> RawImage in the Hierarchy in the Unity Editor (this requires Unity 4.6 and above). Running it should show a live feed of the camera in your view. As of this writing, Unity 5 supports the use of webcams in the free personal edition of Unity 5.

I hope this helps anyone looking for a good way to capture live camera feed in Unity.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible. I highly recommend you look at [**WebcamTexture Unity API**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html). It has some useful functions:

1. [GetPixel()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixel.html) -- Returns pixel color at coordinates (x, y).
2. [GetPixels()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixels.html) -- Get a block of pixel colors.
3. [GetPixels32()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixels32.html) -- Returns the pixels data in raw format.
4. [MarkNonReadable()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.MarkNonReadable.html) -- Marks WebCamTexture as unreadable
5. [Pause()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.Pause.html) -- Pauses the camera.
6. [Play()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.Play.html) -- Starts the camera.
7. [Stop()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.Stop.html) -- Stops the camera.

Answer (score 4):

Bart's answer has a required modification. I used his code and the pic I was getting was black. Required modification is that we have to 
convert TakePhoto to a coroutine and add

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

at the start of Coroutine. (Courtsey @fafase) 
For more details see
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html

You can also refer to

[Take photo using webcam is giving black output[Unity3D]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060412/unity-script-to-take-photo-using-webcam-is-giving-black-output/34060942?noredirect=1#comment55875530_34060942)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can. I created [Android Native camera](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/android-native-camera-) plugin that can open your Android device camera, capture image, record video and save that in the desired location of your device with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to find your webcam device Index by search it in the devices list and select it for webcam texture to play.
you can use this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class GetCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture webCam;
    string your_path = "C:\\Users\\Jay\\Desktop";// any path you want to save your image
    public RawImage display;
    public AspectRatioFitter fit;

    public void Start()
    {
        if(WebCamTexture.devices.Length==0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("can not found any camera!");
            return;
        }
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < WebCamTexture.devices.Length; i++)
        {
            if (WebCamTexture.devices[i].name.ToLower().Contains("your webcam name"))
            {
                Debug.LogError("WebCam Name:" + WebCamTexture.devices[i].name + "   Webcam Index:" + i);
                index = i;
            }
        }

        if (index == -1)
        {
            Debug.LogError("can not found your camera name!");
            return;
        }

        WebCamDevice device = WebCamTexture.devices[index];
        webCam = new WebCamTexture(device.name);
        webCam.Play();
        StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
        display.texture = webCam;

    }

   
    public void Update()
    { 
        float ratio = (float)webCam.width / (float)webCam.height;
        fit.aspectRatio = ratio;


        float ScaleY = webCam.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f : 1f;
        display.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, ScaleY, 1f);

        int orient = -webCam.videoRotationAngle;
        display.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, orient);



    }

    public void callTakePhoto() // call this function in button click event
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
    }
    IEnumerator TakePhoto()  // Start this Coroutine on some button click
    {

        // NOTE - you almost certainly have to do this here:

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // it's a rare case where the Unity doco is pretty clear,
        // http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html
        // be sure to scroll down to the SECOND long example on that doco page 

        Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);
        photo.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
        photo.Apply();

        //Encode to a PNG
        byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToPNG();
        //Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
        File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "\\photo.png", bytes);

    }
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available for this type of functionality called Camera Capture Kit - https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673  and while the functionality provided is geared towards mobile it contains a demo of how you can use the WebCamTexture to take a still image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that without using a third party plugin then @FuntionR solution will help you. But, if you want to save the captured photo to the gallery (Android & iOS)then it's not possible within unity, you have to write native code to transfer photo to gallery and then call it from unity.

Here is a summarise blog which will guide you to achieve your goal.
http://unitydevelopers.blogspot.com/2018/07/pick-image-from-gallery-in-unity3d.html

Edit: Note that, the above thread describes image picking from the gallery, but the same process will be for saving the image to the gallery.