# Take photo using webcam is giving black output[Unity3D]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used the code given by @Bart in the Stackoverflow question [Can I take a photo in Unity using the device's camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496438/can-i-take-a-photo-in-unity-using-the-devices-camera) with some modification. But the result is coming out to be a completely black photo.

I would like to add that the script is attached to a cube which has a renderer.
Also renderer was deprecated hence I had to use GetComponents() for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think at the moment you take the shot, the rendering is not done since rendering happens late in the frame.

You should most likely use a coroutine and wait for the end of the frame

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

or use the callback `OnPostRender` from the camera that is rendering the process.

Comment: can you please elaborate as to where I should add this code. Also please explain the reason in some more detail. I could not understand the rendering part

Comment: Turn your Snapshot method into a coroutine IEnumerator Snapshot and call it with StartCoroutine. At the beginning of the method, use the yield to wait for the end of the frame. Then run the rest of the method. I can't say I am sure it is the solution for you tho. But rendering is done at the end of the frame so it could be that waiting would fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me....I will edit your answer so that it is in detail

Answer (score 1):

Besides

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

invoked in coroutine adding some delay can be required.

For me in avoiding black output works (not the most elegant solution):

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); //Customize
```