# Pass camera image from Java to native library using existing private function

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I'm building a plugin in Java for Unity. I set up the device camera myself in Java, which is working great. However to pass the camera preview data to Unity is proving difficult.

I have tested everything working using the ARToolkit library, which has a function to pass camera preview data to Unity.

However Unity itself has such a function for this as well for camera support in Android, which I would rather like to use. This function is called

```
private final native void nativeVideoFrameCallback(int var1, byte[] var2, int var3, int var4);
```

in the UnityPlayer class, in classes.jar.

You can download the classes.jar for inspection from here: https://github.com/PlayFab/Unity3d_Login_Example_Project/blob/master/Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/android-libs/unity-classes.jar (press the 'Raw' button).

As you can see it is set to private, so I have no option of calling it.

**Original use by UnityPlayer**

nativeVideoFrameCallback is originally called by Unity in:

```
public void onCameraFrame(final com.unity3d.player.a var1, final byte[] var2) {
    final int var3 = var1.a();
    final Size var4 = var1.b();
    this.a(new UnityPlayer.c((byte)0) {
        public final void a() {
            UnityPlayer.this.nativeVideoFrameCallback(var3, var2, var4.width, var4.height);
            var1.a(var2);
        }
    });
}
```

which *is* public, but asks for a non-public variable "com.unity3d.player.a var1", which I can't instantiate.

**A possible solution**

My solution was to create a new native function link for nativeVideoFrameCallback, but it leads to a FatalException. I do not get this exception when not calling my own nativeVideoFrameCallback link, so Unity does  succeed for its own.

```
 UnsatisfiedLinkError: No Implementation found for ...package...UnityPlayer.nativeVideoFrameCallback)int, yte[], int, int).
```

My UnityPlayer class:

```
public class UnityPlayer extends com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> jobs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>();

    public UnityPlayer(ContextWrapper contextWrapper) {
        super(contextWrapper);
    }

    public void addJob(final Camera camera, final int cam, final byte[] data, final int width, final int height) {
        jobs.add(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                nativeVideoFrameCallback(cam, data, width, height);
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
            }
        });
    }

    private final native void nativeVideoFrameCallback(int var1, byte[] var2, int var3, int var4);

    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("main"); // Is this still required? I would think not, as Unity already loads it
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError var1) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Unable to find " + "main");
        } catch (Exception var2) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Unknown error " + var2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeGLThreadJobs() {
        super.executeGLThreadJobs();

        Runnable job = jobs.poll();
        if (job != null) {
            job.run();
        }
    }
}
```

which requires a copy of UnityNativeActivity and the above UnityPlayer instantiation instead of com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.

Comment: What about using WebCamTexture? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496438/can-i-take-a-photo-in-unity-using-the-devices-camera

Comment: I need access to the Android camera. The method I use in Java connects to the backend WebCamTexture, but I use my own camera object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using reflection. It's not optimal to use reflection, so if someone knows a solution without reflection, I will accept that as the answer.

For anyone else looking to manage their own camera on Android with Unity:

```
public class UnityPlayer extends com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> jobs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>();

    public UnityPlayer(ContextWrapper contextWrapper) {
        super(contextWrapper);
    }

    public void addJob(final Camera camera, final int cam, final byte[] data, final int width, final int height) { // execute on opengl thread using jobs
        jobs.add(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                videoFrameCallback(cam, data, width, height);
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] initCamera(int var1, int var2, int var3, int var4) {
        return new int[]{640, 480}; // return width and height of camera
    }

    //    private final native void nativeVideoFrameCallback(int var1, byte[] var2, int var3, int var4); ==> camera id (0 back, 1 front), imagedata, width, height
    private void videoFrameCallback(int var1, byte[] var2, int var3, int var4) {
        try {
            Method m = com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.class.getDeclaredMethod("nativeVideoFrameCallback", Integer.TYPE, byte[].class, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(this, var1, var2, var3, var4);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeGLThreadJobs() {
        super.executeGLThreadJobs();

        Runnable job = jobs.poll();
        if (job != null) {
            job.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm in the midst of implementing something similar. I'm looking at your executeGLThreadJobs. It looks like your jobs.poll() snippet is redundant with the contents of com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer's executeGLThreadJobs, which you call into. Is this intentional, or a simple mistake?

Comment: That's probably a mistake then indeed. You could leave that function out.