# Using player's face from camera as a sprite in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, sprite

Is there a way to get a picture of the player and then cropping the face for a sprite or something?
Like the apps that add your face to a body, but the face would be stored in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496438/can-i-take-a-photo-in-unity-using-the-devices-camera) answer, you can retrieve the picture from the Android Camera and save it as a texture. Then you use a *Texture2D* containing your mask (let's say a circle on the middle with alpha around it) to check which *byte* you want to save and which *byte* will be transparent. Don't forget to set this *Texture2D* import properties to **Advanced** and check **Read/Write enabled**. Finally you can load the newly created picture as a sprite using either Unity *WWW* class or *System.IO.ReadAllBytes*.

Here is a quick implementation of this:

```
[SerializeField]
private Texture2D maskTexture;

private WebCamTexture webCamTexture;

protected void Start()
{
    GetComponent<RawImage>().rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(maskTexture.width, maskTexture.height);

    webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;
    webCamTexture.Play();
}

public void SavePicture()
{
    StartCoroutine(SavePictureCoroutine());
}

private IEnumerator SavePictureCoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    RawImage rawImageToRead = GetComponent<RawImage>();

    //This is to save the current RenderTexture: RenderTexture.GetTemporary() and RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary() can also be used
    RenderTexture previousRenderTexture = RenderTexture.active;
    RenderTexture.active = rawImageToRead.texture as RenderTexture;
    Texture2D renderedTexture = new Texture2D(maskTexture.width, maskTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    renderedTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(Screen.width * 0.5f - maskTexture.width * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f - maskTexture.height * 0.5f, renderedTexture.width, renderedTexture.height), 0, 0);
    renderedTexture.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = previousRenderTexture;
    //----

    for(int i = 0; i < renderedTexture.width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < renderedTexture.height; j++)
        {
            if(maskTexture.GetPixel(i, j).a > 0.5f)
            {
                renderedTexture.SetPixel(i, j, renderedTexture.GetPixel(i, j));
            }
            else
            {
                renderedTexture.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
            }
        }
    }
    renderedTexture.Apply();
    yield return renderedTexture;
    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "YOUR_FILE_NAME"), renderedTexture.EncodeToPNG());
}
```

*(Warning: untested code)*

Also keep in mind to try to provide what you already tried before asking questions: it helps other users understand what and how you want to achieve it.

*Hope this helps,*