# Take photos with Unity3D and send to a server

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, camera

I would like to take pictures with the camera of an android, in base64, and send them to a server and get the response in text format. The app is in Unity3D.

I do not need to save the photo. This should be with a separate thread and repeat the process every second.

Can somebody help me?

Thnx,

[Example server, petition POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj5VJ.png)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496438/can-i-take-a-photo-in-unity-using-the-devices-camera) should help you out with taking the photo.