# Why Camera view is too wide and not clear when trying to take a picture using Unity?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, camera

Trying to take a picture and save in a specified path.I have attached the script to a RawImage.Initially tried [Barts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496438/can-i-take-a-photo-in-unity-using-the-devices-camera).But it was having different rotation and image flipped.So added some code to adjust the rotation and flipping to correct the view.Even though now the camera view looks correct ,it looks like the video feed getting from the camera is too wide and not clear.

Attaching screenshot and code.

[image: zoom-wide]

```
private WebCamTexture camTexture;
// public RawImage Img;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    camTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

    if (devices.Length > 0)
    {
        camTexture.Play();

        //Code below to adjust rotation
        float rotationangle = (360 - camTexture.videoRotationAngle);
        Quaternion rotQuaternion = new Quaternion();
        rotQuaternion.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, rotationangle);
        this.transform.rotation = rotQuaternion;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = camTexture;
    //CODE TO FLIP
    float scaleY = camTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f : 1f;
    this.GetComponent<RawImage>().rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, scaleY, 1f);
}

public void PicTake()
{
    TakePhoto();
}
```

How to correct this.

Comment: Check how you told the camera to scale

Comment: @BugFinder here I am changing only the Y axis.So width will remain the same. Normally Rawimage is having scale (1,1,1).Here I am only flipping with respect to Y axis.

Comment: Then How to flip the camera other  than this method.It should support all screen sizes.

Comment: Initially,I have added a RawImage with scale  (1,1,1) and its anchor stretched in x and y axis.So it covers its parent.

Comment: `its anchor stretched in x and y axis.` there you probably have your issue ;) I would always rather use an [`AspectRatioFitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html)

Comment: Also note that `GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = camTexture;` and `this.GetComponent<RawImage>().rectTransform. ..` are highly unefficient! Use `GetComponent` only **once** e.g. in `Awake`, store the reference and re-use it later

Comment: @derHugo I used Aspect ratio fitter but i had other issues..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737319/how-to-capture-image-with-the-help-of-android-ios-devices-with-correct-width-and

Comment: Since I have used it to stretch in X and Y ,it should support all screen sizes.The width and height should match that of the parent that is how unity should work.For example,I am giving an image as background inside canvas and stretch it in both axis using rect transform by hitting [+].When I try on different screens it will not stretch beyond the canvas and it will support all screen size. Similarly what I am doing with the texture and apply camera texture to it.

Comment: When I tried with aspect ratio and set it to envelope parent,I am getting the same output as before.While testing in mac it is showing correctly but in mobile it is different.

Comment: The question is: Is allways Display-Resolution == Camera-Resolution ? And the same for the aspect ratio ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar troubles when I was testing with Android,iOS,Mac,PC devices. Below is the script I used for solving the scaling & rotation problem.

It uses Unity Quad as background plane and fill the screen.

```
void CalculateBackgroundQuad()
{
    Camera cam = Camera.main;
    ScreenRatio = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;

    BackgroundQuad.transform.SetParent(cam.transform);
    BackgroundQuad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, cam.farClipPlane / 2f);

    float videoRotationAngle = webCamTexture.videoRotationAngle;

    BackgroundQuad.transform.localRotation = baseRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(webCamTexture.videoRotationAngle, Vector3.forward);

    float distance = cam.farClipPlane / 2f;
    float frustumHeight = 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(cam.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

    BackgroundQuad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, distance);
    Vector3 QuadScale = new Vector3(1f, frustumHeight, 1f);

    //adjust the scaling for portrait Mode & Landscape Mode
    if (videoRotationAngle == 0 || videoRotationAngle == 180)
    {
        //landscape mode
        TextureRatio = (float)(webCamTexture.width) / (float)(webCamTexture.height);
        if (ScreenRatio > TextureRatio)
        {
            float SH = ScreenRatio / TextureRatio;
            float TW = TextureRatio * frustumHeight * SH;
            float TH = frustumHeight * (webCamTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1 : 1) * SH;
            QuadScale = new Vector3(TW, TH, 1f);
        }
        else
        {
            float TW = TextureRatio * frustumHeight;
            QuadScale = new Vector3(TW, frustumHeight * (webCamTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1 : 1), 1f);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //portrait mode
        TextureRatio = (float)(webCamTexture.height) / (float)(webCamTexture.width);
        if (ScreenRatio > TextureRatio)
        {
            float SH = ScreenRatio / TextureRatio;
            float TW = frustumHeight * -1f * SH;
            float TH = TW * (webCamTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored ? 1 : -1) * SH;
            QuadScale = new Vector3(TW, TH, 1f);
        }
        else
        {
            float TW = TextureRatio * frustumHeight;
            QuadScale = new Vector3(frustumHeight * -1f, TW * (webCamTexture.videoVerticallyMirrored ? 1 : -1), 1f);
        }
    }
    BackgroundQuad.transform.localScale = QuadScale;
}
```

The above script should work on all devices. Just simple math solution.