# Taking a picture with web cam in unity but can't attach script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been coding for many many moons now but I'm very new to unity and C#. Currently, I'm trying create a script to both display a camera feed and when a button is pressed, take a still of that feed so that I can run an OCR algorithm on it. I took most of my code (and consequently the code comments) from here: [Can I take a photo in Unity using the device's camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496438/can-i-take-a-photo-in-unity-using-the-devices-camera)

The problem I'm having is that I keep getting this error in unity which prevents me from even running the code:

> Assets/Scripts/WebCam.cs(22,42): error CS0103: The name 'webCamTexture' does not exist in the current context

Line 22 is in the TakePhoto() function of my code. This seems to be an issue with scope but as far as I can tell, with my very limited grasp of C#, the "webCamTexture" variable is in the class scope. So as such it should be accessible in any of class WebCam's methods. But as I said before I'm still very new to C# and Unity, so maybe I'm just missing something.

It might be worth noting, for those who are just C# people and haven't used Unity before, that the start() function is supposed to run immediately when the app starts. So, in theory, I expect that the "webCamTexture" variable should always have a non-null value by the time the TakePhoto() function gets executed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's there code in question:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class WebCamScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public RawImage rawimage;
    private WebCamTexture webcamTexture;

    private void Start() 
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello World!: WebCamScript Start()");

        if (webcamTexture == null)
        {
            webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        }

        rawimage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;

        if (!webcamTexture.isPlaying)
        {
            webcamTexture.Play();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator TakePhoto()  // Start this Coroutine on some button click
    {

        // NOTE - you almost certainly have to do this here:

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); 

        // it's a rare case where the Unity doco is pretty clear,
        // http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html
        // be sure to scroll down to the SECOND long example on that doco page 

        Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height);
        photo.SetPixels(webcamTexture.GetPixels());
        photo.Apply();

        // //Encode to a PNG
        // byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToPNG();
        // //Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
        // File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "photo.png", bytes);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Was a typo. Looks like all I needed was a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks all. That being said I'm still having some issues that are making me scratch my head. I'm still not seeing my "takePhoto" function when I go to link it to my button. Any ideas why? I updated my code above to reflect it's current state. See photo:
[missing script in drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROjg7.png)

Comment: Typo.  Your variable is ```webcamTexture``` but you're asking for ```webCamTexture```.

Comment: A quick note on your WaitForEndOfFrame, you could always change the "script execution order" so that this script always runs after other scripts, and still do the capture during Update.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your exact code, you defined a webcamTexture variable but you are trying to use webCamTexture : watch out for upper/lowercase, keep your naming consistent :)

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) ;)