# TakePhoto Coroutine doesnt click Picture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve a picture clicking app in unity and I already made a script, but the TakePhoto Coroutine doesnt seem to work when I press a button, I am using Start and Update functions from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6NXkZWXHnc&t=640s) and TakePhoto Coroutine from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496438/can-i-take-a-photo-in-unity-using-the-devices-camera#:%7E:text=You%20will%20want%20to%20look,save%20this%20in%20a%20Texture2D) solution. Can someone please help me fix this??

This is my Code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.IO;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


public class GetCam: MonoBehaviour 
{
    WebCamTexture webCam;
    string your_path = "C:\\Users\\Jay\\Desktop";
    public RawImage display;
    public AspectRatioFitter fit;

    public void Start() 
    {
         webCam = new WebCamTexture();
         webCam.Play();
         StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
         display.texture = webCam;
         
    }

    public void lol(){         //starts the coroutine

        StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
    }
 
    public void Update(){


        float ratio = (float)webCam.width / (float)webCam.height;
        fit.aspectRatio = ratio;


        float ScaleY = webCam.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f: 1f;
        display.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(1f,ScaleY, 1f);

        int orient = -webCam.videoRotationAngle;
        display.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,orient);


        
    }

    IEnumerator TakePhoto()  // Start this Coroutine on some button click
    {

    // NOTE - you almost certainly have to do this here:

     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); 

    // it's a rare case where the Unity doco is pretty clear,
    // http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html
    // be sure to scroll down to the SECOND long example on that doco page 

        Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);
        photo.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
        photo.Apply();

        //Encode to a PNG
        byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToPNG();
        //Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
        File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "photo.png", bytes);
        //lol
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi change your start function to something like this:

```
 public void Start()
{
    if(WebCamTexture.devices.Length==0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("can not found any camera!");
        return;
    }
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < WebCamTexture.devices.Length; i++)
    {
        if (WebCamTexture.devices[i].name.ToLower().Contains("your webcam name"))
        {
            Debug.LogError("WebCam Name:" + WebCamTexture.devices[i].name + "   Webcam Index:" + i);
            index = i;
        }
    }

    if (index == -1)
    {
        Debug.LogError("can not found your camera name!");
        return;
    }

    WebCamDevice device = WebCamTexture.devices[index];
    webCam = new WebCamTexture(device.name);
    webCam.Play();
    StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
    display.texture = webCam;

}
```

lien 87:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "photo.png", bytes);
```

change it to

```
File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "\\photo.png", bytes);
```

an it will be work. good luck.

complete code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class GetCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture webCam;
    string your_path = "C:\\Users\\Jay\\Desktop";
    public RawImage display;
    public AspectRatioFitter fit;

    public void Start()
    {
        if(WebCamTexture.devices.Length==0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("can not found any camera!");
            return;
        }
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < WebCamTexture.devices.Length; i++)
        {
            if (WebCamTexture.devices[i].name.ToLower().Contains("your webcam name"))
            {
                Debug.LogError("WebCam Name:" + WebCamTexture.devices[i].name + "   Webcam Index:" + i);
                index = i;
            }
        }

        if (index == -1)
        {
            Debug.LogError("can not found your camera name!");
            return;
        }

        WebCamDevice device = WebCamTexture.devices[index];
        webCam = new WebCamTexture(device.name);
        webCam.Play();
        StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
        display.texture = webCam;

    }

   
    public void Update()
    {


        float ratio = (float)webCam.width / (float)webCam.height;
        fit.aspectRatio = ratio;


        float ScaleY = webCam.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f : 1f;
        display.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, ScaleY, 1f);

        int orient = -webCam.videoRotationAngle;
        display.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, orient);



    }

    public void callTakePhoto()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
    }
    IEnumerator TakePhoto()  // Start this Coroutine on some button click
    {

        // NOTE - you almost certainly have to do this here:

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // it's a rare case where the Unity doco is pretty clear,
        // http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html
        // be sure to scroll down to the SECOND long example on that doco page 

        Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);
        photo.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
        photo.Apply();

        //Encode to a PNG
        byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToPNG();
        //Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
        File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "\\photo.png", bytes);
        //lol
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the code i fixed it a bit since it couldnt fetch my webcam name so i had to remove and edit some lines of code
Now its working perfectly thank you very much!